# Django: How to show image path after saving a form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple form with a CharField, ImageField and a TextField. When I enter text, pick an image and save the form like so:

```
def item_new(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

a new instance of my model with the image is saved. But in the form on my site it now says "no file selected" in the ImageField, whereas the entered text in the other fields is shown. So, how can I make it show the path of the selected file instead?

Comment: You can't. Browsers don't let you for security reasons. You need to show the existing value separately from the field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Had a misunderstanding anyway. The text is remembered by the browser, right? And saving this form again will create a new instance. I will have to load the newly created instance to make changes. Don't know how to go about that, as I need the pk/id.

Comment: To clarify, are you just trying to show the newly saved data in a few after submission or are you wanting to reload the original data so you could save a new instance?

Comment: Yes, I want to show the newly saved data, to edit it further.